# iOS Retrieving valueForKey?

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS and working on a basic app, it's currently working with `SSKeychain` and `AFNetworking` to interact with an API. When you log in with the app I retrieve and set the auth_token in my CredentialStore class, I need to send the auth token to the API as a http header to get access. How can I retrieve the token that I'm storing in the CredentialStore class in my HomeViewController.

Here is my CredentialStore:

```
#import "GFCredentialStore.h"
#import "SSKeychain.h"

#define SERVICE_NAME @"Groupify"
#define AUTH_TOKEN_KEY @"auth_token"

@implementation GFCredentialStore : NSObject

- (BOOL)isLoggedIn {
    return [self authToken] != nil;
}

- (void)clearSavedCredentials {
    [self setAuthToken:nil];
}

- (NSString *)authToken {
    return [self secureValueForKey:AUTH_TOKEN_KEY];
}

- (void)setAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken {
    [self setSecureValue:authToken forKey:AUTH_TOKEN_KEY];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"token-changed" object:self];
}

- (void)setSecureValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (value) {
        [SSKeychain setPassword:value
                     forService:SERVICE_NAME
                        account:key];
    } else {
        [SSKeychain deletePasswordForService:SERVICE_NAME account:key];
    }
}

- (NSString *)secureValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [SSKeychain passwordForService:SERVICE_NAME account:key];
}

@end
```

Here I am trying to retrieve the authToken value and set it to a string so that I can send it as a http header:

```
#import "GFHomeViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import "GFCredentialStore.h"

#define kBaseURL "http://localhost:3000/"
#define kHomeURL "newsfeed.json"

@interface GFHomeViewController ()
@end

@implementation GFHomeViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s", kBaseURL, kHomeURL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue: forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];

    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `SSKeychain` is saving and returning values to/from the keychain, I'd think you would simply be able to do something like this

```
GFCredentialStore *credentialStore = [[CGCredentialStore alloc] init];

if ([credentialStore isLoggedIn]) {
    NSString *authToken = [credentialStore authToken];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];
} else {
    // prompt/display controller for login
}
```

If I'm missing something in your problem/issue you're having, please clarify your question, and I'll have another go at it.

Comment: Going to try this now and will let you know.

Comment: Works a treat! Another quick question, I actually wrote your answer first and assumed it was wrong as I put a breakpoint on the line where I set the `NSString *authToken` in the HomeViewController. When it stops at that breakpoint it says it's nil in the console. But one line afterwards it becomes the correct auth token value. In xcode should you set a breakpoint to the line after to check if a value has been set?

Comment: AFAIK, a breakpoint executes *before* executing the line that it's set on. So, if you set a breakpoint *on the line* that you create and set a variable, I would guess that you would get an unknown name error for the variable (I'd be surprised if it returned `nil` at that point for the iVar, but I wouldn't worry about it :] )